# How to get the type of device(iphone or ipad) in cocos application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

how can i get the type of device, which is launched my application?
i want to show different scenes(one for iphone and another for ipad) for different devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/8107 reply no. 2 by petrusali

learn to love your cocos2d forums

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the `UIDevice` class. Look for `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad`. Using this you can identify whether the device in question is a iPad